# mysql trigger inserting duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, triggers, duplicates

This is the first time I'm having to create a trigger in mysql.  I'm trying to update a small log table (4 columns) one of which is a URL.  I have it working except I can't figure out how to prevent it from inserting 2 rows when the trigger fires.  I cannot create a unique index on the url row because of max key length.  Any suggestions on other means?  I've tried insert via select statements and using ON DUPLICATE KEY with no success.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`%` TRIGGER `upd_url_prod` AFTER UPDATE ON  `products` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO my_changes (ext_id,url,changetime)
VALUES (NEW.external_id,NEW.detail_url,NOW());
```

END

Comment: Are you able to share your full trigger creation code, and the steps that lead up to the trigger being activated. Theres a few different processes in between that could make the data insert twice.

Comment: I updated with full trigger code.  This is behind a wordpress site and I'm using a add-on to try import products and then want to be able to log when it's updated via this trigger.  Coming from SQL Server anytime I need more visibility into what the db or its objects are doing I would use profiler - is there anything similar any would suggest for doing so here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your update query on that trigger fires. Perhaps that query is firing two time and trigger is firing. check your script where update query is running and log that query.

Comment: So you are in fact correct - when I profile the initial UPDATE on the table I have the trigger on it appears to be running 2 identical updates.  Any ideas why that would be? And what I can do to avoid this?